# How to show parameters which were passed into the query, on the report

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, parameter-passing, reportviewer

In my .NET winforms application I'm using `ReportViewer`. So I just create a `DataSet` and configure an `DataAdapter` and then use that `DataSet` in report.rdlc to design the report. Finally I bind that report to report viewer.

This is the query behind the report

```
SELECT reference AS Month, payment_date AS Date, SUM(total_records) AS Records, SUM(total_amount) AS Amount, ROUND(SUM(total_amount) / SUM(total_records), 2) AS Average
FROM Payment
GROUP BY reference, payment_date
HAVING (payment_date BETWEEN @fromDate AND @toDate)
```

Then I pass parameters to the adapter and show the report as follows...

```
    private void btnShowReport_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.PaymentTableAdapter.Fill(this.DataSetWagesPaymentSummary.Payment,dtpFrom.Value.ToString(),dtpTo.Value.ToString());

        this.rpWagesSummary.RefreshReport();
    }
```

**[dtpFrom and dtpTo are DateTimePickers]**

Now What I'm trying to do is I just want to show these `@toDate` and `@fromDate` parameters in the report like this...

---

```
PAYMENT SUMMARY REPORT 
FROM 1/1/2014 TO 31/1/2014
```

---

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to create a parameter in the report:

1. Report Data - Parameters
2. Right click - Add New Parameter, for example toDate.

Next, you need to pass the parameter into the report.

```
ReportParameter rp1 = new ReportParameter("toDate", dtpFrom.Value.ToString());
this.reportViewer1.LocalReport.SetParameters(new ReportParameter[] { rp1 });
```

Then add a textbox in your report and set the expression.

For example:

```
=Parameters!toDate.Value
```